# Solidity Error when doing a transaction - cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, metamask, ethers.js

I get this error when doing a transaction through Metamask using this Solidity contract:

The error:

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit 
[ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] 
(reason="execution reverted", method="estimateGas", transaction=
{"from":"0x80CB17D85034EDb2Ea1D4BC7d9d512c5dD0d6000",
"to":"0x9d3cA4786e3584b198400F82CA883A581Bd3c4C0","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x057289b00c97"},
"data":"0xde905f830000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000c99da3a663604c43f6296f3f95e9ea7b6481f01f000000000000000000000000bb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000143956764a6a6c33674a726f6b6762767a456d4e64000000000000000000000000","accessList":null}, error={"code":-32603,"message":"Internal JSON-RPC error.","data":{"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"},"stack":"{\n  \"code\": -32603,\n  \"message\": \"Internal JSON-RPC error.\",\n  \"data\": {\n    \"code\": -32000,\n    \"message\": \"execution reverted\"\n  }
```

Solidity Code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

// Import this file to use console.log
import "hardhat/console.sol";



contract CryptoPayments {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint256 public ownerPercentage;
    address payable public owner;

    event NewPayment(string txId, address from, address to, address token, uint256 when);

    constructor() payable {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        ownerPercentage = 5;
    }

    function createPayment(string memory txId, address payable seller, address token) public payable {    
        uint256 ownerPortion = msg.value.mul(ownerPercentage).div(100);
        uint256 sellerPortion = msg.value - ownerPortion;

        IERC20 _token = IERC20(token);
        
        _token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), msg.value);

        _token.transfer(owner, ownerPortion);
        _token.transfer(seller, sellerPortion);

        emit NewPayment(txId, msg.sender, seller, token, block.timestamp);
    }

    function setOwnerPercentage(uint256 percentage) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You aren't the owner");

        ownerPercentage = percentage;
    }

    function setOwner(address newOwner) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You aren't the owner");
        owner = payable(newOwner);
    }
}
```

JS code responsible for the execution:

```js
const [ token, setToken ] = useState({
    bnb: {
        name: 'WBNB',
        selected: false,
        address: "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"
    },
});

const contractAddr = "<CONTRACT_ADDR_HERE>"
const trxData = {seller_wallet_address: "<WALLET_ADDRESS_HERE>"}

async function initiatePayment(){
   const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
   const signer = provider.getSigner()

   let tokenAbi = ["function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns 
   (bool success)"];
   
   let tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(token['bnb'].address, tokenAbi, signer);
   await tokenContract.approve(contractAddr, value);

   const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddr, ctrct.abi, signer)
   const val = await contract.createPayment(id, trxData.seller_wallet_address, 
   token['bnb'].address, {value});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your contract `createPayment`

```
function createPayment(string memory txId, 
                       address payable seller, 
                       address token) public payable
```

on client side, you are not passing correct arguments:

```
const val = await contract.createPayment(id, 
                                         trxData.seller_wallet_address, 
                                         token['bnb'].address, 
                                         {value});
```

what is`id` argument. Make sure you are passing correct value types. If error still persists, make sure your metamask is connected to the correct network

Comment: The `{value}` parameter is passed as the `msg.value` of the contract. It does not need to be included in the arguments in the function definition. `txId` is the id parameter

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe I forgot that {value} is option object, it looked like a value. where is "id" defined. make sure it is string value. if the parameter types are correct, make sure you are on correct network on metamask